# Centering image in wordpress theme css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is how header looks already:

HTML

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-right">
    <a href="#"><img class="site-logo" src="logo.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <nav>...</nav>
  </div>

</div>
```

with default css

I want to have logo centered in the whole row (in the middle of screen) but without changing nav at all.

Comment: you try changing `text-right` to `text-center`?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd expect you to put the logo in a new center column. Does that leave enough room for the navbar? Without seeing it it's hard to offer advice.

Comment: @isherwood it makes nav elements like 'Contact' wrap on certain width and I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On md sceen it would be imposible since you have col-md-6 on both divs, so each colum takes a half of the screen,on the other sm and xs screens you can achieve this doing the following
Change this line:

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 text-right">
```

To

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
```

Hope it could help.